# forcing the Jersey Grizzly server to authenicate

Tags: jersey, grizzly

I am performing acceptance tests against REST services written using Jersey.  In my services, I need to get the name of the user who successfully authenticated (BASIC) using:

```
@Context private SecurityContext securityContext; //at class level

String username = securityContext.getUserPrincipal().getName()  //inside a resource
```

I am using the Jersey client API and running against the Grizzly server.  I set up the server as follows:

```
public class BaseResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

   public BaseResourceTest() throws Exception {

    super(new WebAppDescriptor.Builder("net.tds.adm.na.batchcut")
        .contextPath(baseUri.getPath())
        .contextParam("contextConfigLocation","classpath:testContext.xml")
        .initParam("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature",
            "true").servletClass(SpringServlet.class)
        .contextListenerClass(ContextLoaderListener.class)
        .build());

     }

.......

}
```

In my tests, I pass an authorization header as follows:

```
WebResource resource = resource().path(_url);
return resource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE).header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, new String(Base64.encode("judge:smails"))).post(ClientResponse.class, _formData);
```

However, in my resources I get an NPE when trying to get the user name.  I think I need to get the server to actively authenticate against a realm but I haven't found how to configure the server to do this.  Has anybody had any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Grizzly HttpServer doesn't support authentication at the moment.
But here you can find a simple example how to implement authentication using Jersey Filter.

http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2013/01/24/jersey-jax-rs-implements-a-http-basic-auth-decoder/